# How to move a file with $1 on it's name with a makefile

Tags: makefile

I want to move a file with "$1" on it's name, for example file$1.txt. How to write the command instead of letting it execute the variable 1?

Comment: could you please provide what you need to get as output ?

Answer (score 0):

By using quotes:

```
echo 'var$1'
```

Or by escaping the $:

```
echo var\$1
```

In a makefile you must escape the $ by another $, which will generate a single $, and that must be escaped for use in the shell:

```
echo var \$$1
```

(Note that the \ does not need to be escaped in the makefile.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to `mv`the file objects which contains the `$` in the name:

For example:

```
 touch file\$\1
```

A file will be created with name `file$1`

Now test for `mv` the file to new name:

```
mv file\$\1 file2
```

Output:

The file will be renamed to file2

In the makefile, you need to use another `$` to escape `$`.

Example:

```
echo print var\$$1
```

Comment: @Israel P: Is this what you are expecting ?

Comment: I'm trying to do this inside a makefile. I want to move a object with $1 on it's name. I thought the commands on shell would work. But mv object'$1' or mv object\$1 still executing the variable and returning object'' and object\ respectively.

Comment: `mv` command is used to move/rename the files. Is the object is the file ?

Comment: Yes, it's a file but has $1 on it's name as object$1.class

Comment: @IsraelP: Updated. Is this you are expecting ?

Comment: Yes. But curiously it doesn't work inside a makefile. @Jos said how to do it in a makefile. Thanks for the answers and I should've asked for a makefile directly.

Comment: @IsraelP: Yes if you can say it in question description it would be helpful to provide answers. Now its updated

Answer (score 0):

Escaping characters of **ASCII codes is using backsplash "\"**. Using backslash you can escape characters to their original form as you using a backslash before a character. For example, I wanna a slash "/" I just need type **"\/"**  instead of type "/".
**Here you need a "$" you can just type "\$", then you can get it.**